# Div Hiding when minimize the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

We aligned a "Call to Action Box" div based on Container Div.It is aligned properly in  normal browser view but problem is When we minimize the browser window "call to action" div is not visible to the user.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="PosRel">
            <div class="PosAbsol">
                <div  class="MsgContainer">
                            <div class="MsgDisplay">Call To Action</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.PosRel {
    position: relative;
}

.PosAbsol {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.MsgContainer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

.MsgDisplay {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 58px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 18px 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: When you minimise the browser window the whole page is not visible to the user...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Can you please let us know what is your requirement. I tested your HTML and CSS. it is completely mess up with styling. and font color is also white.

Comment: @HarshadaChavan : "Call to Action" div is not visible

Comment: @nnnnnn : only "Call to Action" div is hiding

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't think he means minimizing to the toolbar, he just means making the window small.

Answer (score 0):

are you want this : )

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1230px) and (min-width:990px){ 
 // CSS code
 }
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
// CSS code
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
// CSS code
}
```